# Quickblox not initializing in android devices below API 20

Tags: android, quickblox

I am working on a `quickblox` application and its `working fine for devices with API 20 or above`.

My problem is that my `application crashes in devices below API level 20`.

Do `Quickblox only support devices with API 20 or above?` Or i need to do some modification in my code?

I am using quickblox github demo in my application.

Comment: Do you use pure samples or with any changes? Please provide log with error. Note: QuickBlox Android SDK supports min Android API 14.

Comment: @ValentynTereshchenko i am using pure sample till the initialization part, thats not working and log is showing `Exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.quickblox.sample.core.utils.configs.ConfigParser ` but this exception only comes in devices below 20 API

Comment: do you use proguard? Can you reproduce this error on samples but not on your project?

Answer (score 1):

try to intialize your quickblox by this method.

```
 if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT<Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
            QBSettings.getInstance().setStoringMehanism(StoringMechanism.UNSECURED);
        }else{
            QBSettings.getInstance().setStoringMehanism(StoringMechanism.SECURED);
        }
```

Comment: your minimum SDK should be 19